# MapColorFrameToDepthFrame (Unhandled Exception, Access Violation)

Tags: c++, kinect-sdk

I tried to align the depth image with color image using the MapColorFrameToDepthFrame function but there is a problem at this line of code (Unhandled Exception, Access Violation):

```
pMapper->MapColorFrameToDepthFrame(
        NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR,
        NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,
        NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,
        640 * 480, 
        (NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_PIXEL*)LockedRect.Pitch,
        640 * 480, 
        depthPoints);
```

Here is the code of the Nui_GotDepthAlert:

```
bool CSkeletalViewerApp::Nui_GotDepthAlert( ){
NUI_IMAGE_FRAME imageFrame;
bool processedFrame = true;

HRESULT hr = m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(
    m_pDepthStreamHandle,
    0,
    &imageFrame );

if ( FAILED( hr ) )
{
    return false;
}

m_depthTimeStamp = imageFrame.liTimeStamp;

INuiFrameTexture * pTexture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
NUI_LOCKED_RECT LockedRect;
pTexture->LockRect( 0, &LockedRect, NULL, 0 );
if ( 0 != LockedRect.Pitch )
{
    INuiCoordinateMapper* pMapper;
    NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_POINT* depthPoints;

    depthPoints = new NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_POINT[640 * 480];
    m_pNuiSensor->NuiGetCoordinateMapper(&pMapper);

    //NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_PIXEL* pdepthpixel = (NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_PIXEL*)LockedRect.Pitch;

    pMapper->MapColorFrameToDepthFrame(
        NUI_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR,
        NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,
        NUI_IMAGE_RESOLUTION_640x480,
        640 * 480, 
        (NUI_DEPTH_IMAGE_PIXEL*)LockedRect.Pitch,
        640 * 480, 
        depthPoints);

    //memcpy(m_depthD16, LockedRect.pBits, LockedRect.size);

    DWORD frameWidth, frameHeight;

    NuiImageResolutionToSize( imageFrame.eResolution, frameWidth, frameHeight );

    // draw the bits to the bitmap
    BYTE * rgbrun = m_depthRGBX;
    const USHORT * pBufferRun = (const USHORT *)LockedRect.pBits;

    depthData = (USHORT *)LockedRect.pBits;


    // end pixel is start + width*height - 1
    const USHORT * pBufferEnd = pBufferRun + (frameWidth * frameHeight);

    assert( frameWidth * frameHeight * g_BytesPerPixel <= ARRAYSIZE(m_depthRGBX) );
    USHORT depth;
    USHORT* depth1=(USHORT *)LockedRect.pBits;
    USHORT realDepth;
    while ( pBufferRun < pBufferEnd )//&& pDepth < depthEnd)
    {
        /**depthValues = pDepth->depth;
        depthValues++;*/

        //USHORT depth     = *pBufferRun;
        depth     = *pBufferRun;
        USHORT realDepth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(depth);
        USHORT player    = NuiDepthPixelToPlayerIndex(depth);

        // transform 13-bit depth information into an 8-bit intensity appropriate
        // for display (we disregard information in most significant bit)
        BYTE intensity = static_cast<BYTE>(~(realDepth >> 4));

        // tint the intensity by dividing by per-player values
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity >> g_IntensityShiftByPlayerB[player];
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity >> g_IntensityShiftByPlayerG[player];
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity >> g_IntensityShiftByPlayerR[player];

        // no alpha information, skip the last byte
        ++rgbrun;

        ++pBufferRun;
    }



    m_pDrawDepth->Draw( m_depthRGBX, frameWidth * frameHeight * g_BytesPerPixel );


}
else
{
    processedFrame = false;
    OutputDebugString( L"Buffer length of received texture is bogus\r\n" );
}

pTexture->UnlockRect( 0 );

if(m_pDepthStreamHandle != NULL)
    m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageStreamReleaseFrame( m_pDepthStreamHandle, &imageFrame );  




return processedFrame;
```

}

Could someone tell me how to fix this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

there,

I was having some similar problems, after struggling long time on it and finally find the trick of it.

First problem i found in your code is in the MapColorFrameToDepthFrame function, the fifth parameter seems should be LockedRect.pBits.

Second problem is how to define the pTexture,

```
INuiFrameTexture* pTexture = imageFrame.pFrameTexture;
```

will not work. You have to use

```
m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageFrameGetDepthImagePixelFrameTexture(m_hDepthStreamHandle, &imageFrame, &bNearMode, &pTexture)
```

remember to check if you succeeded on this function. I have dig deep to find why.

Third problem is, you have to

```
delete[] depthPoints;
```

after use to release to memory for it, because you used new operator on it.

After all of this, my code finally is working. Hope it will be helpful for you.

Thanks.